# How do I reset the inner embedded key?

Tags: associations

I have a `Association`:

```
ass = <|"flags" -> <|"a" -> 8|>, 
   "shapes" -> {<|"label" -> "ob", "len" -> 5, 
      "shape_type" -> "polygon", "flags" -> <||>|>}, 
   "imagePath" -> "44505.jpg"|>;
```

How to reset the key `"len"` from `5` into `0`?

Comment: Is the `{}` deliberate?

Comment: @xzczd When I use `Import[json,"RawJSON"]` I will get the `{}`

Comment: Then is it necessary for subsequent work? Can we simply remove it?

Comment: @xzczd I'm afraid I can't, because I have to write it back after the data is processed

Comment: It seems to me that an important issue here is whether you require "in-place" modification (@xzczd's answer) or whether you want an new association with a modified key (leaving ass unmodified, @Domen's answer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks to [eldo's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/288978/1871), I notice the following is actually allowed:

```
ass[["shapes", 1, "len"]] = 0;

ass
(*
<|"flags" -> <|"a" -> 8|>, 
 "shapes" -> {<|"label" -> "ob", "len" -> 0, "shape_type" -> "polygon", 
    "flags" -> <||>|>}, "imagePath" -> "44505.jpg"|>
 *)
```

Comment: Is this method in the documentation?

Comment: @yode I fail to find it, at least it doesn't seem to be in document of `Association` :) . Perhaps WRI thinks that, since the `assoc[key]=val` syntax, `t[[spec]]=value` syntax and `{<|"a" -> x, "b" -> {y, z}|>}[[1, "b", 2]]` syntax are all documented, one should be able to deduce this out?

Comment: I think this is somehow "hinted" in the second bullet point in the documentation for `Association`: _An Association acts like a **symbolically indexed list**. The value associated with a given key can be extracted by using the part specification Key[key]. If key is a string, Key can be omitted._

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`ReplacePart`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplacePart.html).

```
ReplacePart[ass, {"shapes", 1, "len"} -> 0]
(* <|"flags" -> <|"a" -> 8|>, 
     "shapes" -> {<|"label" -> "ob", "len" -> 0, 
     "shape_type" -> "polygon", "flags" -> <||>|>}, 
     "imagePath" -> "44505.jpg"|> *)
```

Answer (score 1):

An explicit solution (useful f.e. if one would like to rename or delist `shapes`:

```
<|
   KeyTake["flags"] @ ass, 
   "new_shapes" -> <|ass[["shapes", 1]], "len" -> 0|>, 
   KeyTake["imagePath"] @ ass
|>
```

With `ReplaceAt` we can match `Pattern`s:

```
ds = ReplaceAt[ass, _?NumberQ -> 0, {Key["shapes"], 1, Key["len"]}]

ds // Dataset
```

[image]